# JSONDecodeError: How to see where the character is wrong?

Tags: python, json

I have this error : JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 1206 (char 1205) in Python.

At beginning I have this, looks like this (str type):

```
    '{"results": [
        {"first": "...","second": "...","good": true,"missing": false,"name": "..."},
        {"first": "...","second": "...","good": true,"missing": false,"name": "..."},
    {"first": "...","second": "...","good": true,"missing": false,"name": "..."},
    ],
"count1": 12,"count2": 1,"count3": 0.61156}'
```

When I do: json.loads(result_above) I have the error

I would like to know where is the char 1205.

How can I do this ?

Comment: paste it into a pretty printer such as  https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: `print(result_above[1200:1210])` will show you part of the JSON around the error.

Comment: Thanks, I have this: 5.1 Chaq
Looks like a big space between number 1 and C

Comment: Thank it was the big space